# Don't show my app in recent app

Tags: android

I want Don't show my app in recent app when user run or close my app in hdevice

my purpose is:
user Disabling to run my app

i am sorry for bad speak .

Comment: android:excludeFromRecents="true"

Comment: very thanks :X this work successfully

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Try this..

For your every **activity** `android:excludeFromRecents="true"`

```
<activity
        android:name=".Activity"
        android:excludeFromRecents="true" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

For more information refer this [doc](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html)

Answer (score 6):

From [Android Doc](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html)

Read [this](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#exclude).

> android:excludeFromRecents
>
> Whether or not the task initiated by this
>   activity should be excluded from the list of recently used
>   applications ("recent apps"). That is, when this activity is the root
>   activity of a new task, this attribute determines whether the task
>   should not appear in the list of recent apps. Set "true" if the task
>   should be excluded from the list; set "false" if it should be
>   included. The default value is "false".

add `android:excludeFromRecents="true"` in your xml (AndroidManifest.xml) for the activity tag

Answer (score 5):

[`excludeFromRecents`](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#exclude) is what you are looking for.
Just add this to your `Activity` tag in the  `AndroidManifest.xml`:

```
android:excludeFromRecents="true"
```